# TFS 2008: Query Changesets by User and export information to Excel

Tags: changeset

Doesn't seem to be a question or answer about this. I need to use TFS2008 to query a user's changesets and export the results to Excel.

The catch is that I not only need changeset number, user, and date checked in, but I also need the files affected by the checkin. It's worth nothing that I have a co-worker who has presented the results of a similar query he did a while ago, but he cannot remember how it was done.

I've used Ctrl+G from Source Control Explorer to query changesets, but this dialog will not allow me to export to Excel and will not show me the files affected unless I double-click the changeset. It would be very labor-intensive to try to write this all by hand by clicking through dialog windows. Maybe there's a way to do it through the Work Item Query utility? Any help would be appreciated.

The following is an example of the format I need:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hopes this might help you

```
SELECT TOP 10
V.ChildItem AS [File Modified],
V.Command AS [Check-In-Action],
V.ParentPath AS [Modified File Path],
CS.ChangeSetId,
CS.CreationDate AS [Date]
FROM tbl_Changeset CS
INNER JOIN tbl_Identity I ON I.IdentityID = CS.OwnerID
INNER JOIN tbl_Version V ON V.VersionFrom = CS.ChangesetID
ORDER BY CS.CreationDate DESC
```

Here V.Command stands for

```
* Edit = 2
* Type = 4
* Add folder = 5
* Add file = 7
* Rename = 8
* Rename,edit = 10
* Delete = 16
* Delete,rename = 24
* Undelete = 32
* Undelete,edit = 34
* Branch = 68
* Branch,delete = 84
* Merge = 128
* Merge, edit = 130
* Merge,type,edit = 134
* Merge, rename, edit = 138
* Merge,delete = 144
* Merge,delete,rename = 152
* Merge,undelete = 160
* Merge,undelete,edit = 162
* Merge,branch = 196
* Merge,branch,edit = 198
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can build a query from VS interface that would return such a result set. Your best bet would be to query databases directly.

The name of files might not be found in TFS warehouse because it is too much of a detail to be contained in the warehouse so you might have to query the actual TFS database directly. It is worth noting here that "accessing TFS DB directly" is something neither recommended nor supported/documented by Microsoft, but you gotta do what you gotta do. (Be careful, never ever change anything in the DB)

I've tried building a sample query for you but I am using TFS2010. Both DB and warehouse schemas have changed dramatically in TFS 2010 so my query won't be any help to you.

If you manage to build a query, you can run it through Excel and get results directly into Excel.